# AspNetMembershipProvider login attempts message

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add a label to my login screen which states the user is locked out once 3 failed attempts are submitted. Currently, if the user enters the password incorrectly, this error appears:

> Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.

Once the password has been entered incorrectly 3 times, the account becomes locked out, which is what I want, however this message stays the same and does not change.

**How can I change this to a different message which states the user as locked out?**

from what I can tell, the `failureNotification` class is being called within my login.aspx file, which returns the above message.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="logInBtn">
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" Text="LOG IN" Width="112" Height="38" CssClass="buttonStyle" />
</div>

<span class="failureNotification">
<asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" />
</span>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" />
```

If any more information is required please let me know, this is not my area of expertise so apologies if anything important is missed

AspNetMembershipProvider line from Web.config:

```
<add name="AspNetMembershipProvider"
 type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
 connectionStringName="_IntrinsicData"
 applicationName="MYAPPLICATION" 
 requiresUniqueEmail="false"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
 minRequiredPasswordLength="5" 
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" />
```

***when clicking on the button, it only opens up the aspx file:***

[image]

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1268988.aspx?display+a+message+if+account+is+locked+out

Comment: thankyou for your response, I am struggling to find out where to add that code block, any pointers?

Comment: you have a login button, try the click event for that

Comment: i have added an image of what happens when clicking on the login button, it just opens up the aspx code, nothing else like C#